# Call function after every minute on Android Device

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager

I want to call a function or API for every minute (on the dot).

*Example:
If I launch my app at 06:05:15 AM, then I need to call the method at 06:06:00 AM, again at 06:07:00 AM and so on..*

Currently, I'm using Time Scheduler

```
private void callTimer()
{
    final Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // getCurrentTime();

            Log.d("=============>>>>","timer triggered");
        }
    }, 0,60000);

}
```

But this calls the function a minute after I launch the app.

*Example: If the current time is 06:06:15 AM, it calls the method again at 06:07:15 AM.  I need this to be called on the dot (i.e. After 45 seconds at 06.07.00 AM).*

Is it OK to use a Timer or should I use AlarmManager?
Please help.

Comment: On each timer, instead of scheduling for 60000 ms, sleep for 60000-time_in_ms%60000 milliseconds.  In other words, set each timeout for the remaining time in the minute.

Comment: if you want to repeating task, use Alarm Manager to run things on particular time like exactly in 06:07:00 am and every minute after that.

Comment: make service for that.....it will run continuously

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve from this..

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

int stopFor = 60 - second;


 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callTimer();
                }
            }, stopFor * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        YourFunction();
    }
}, 3100);//your time
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(yourRunnable);// this will call immediately and run youRunnable defined in post.

    Runnable yourRunnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          callTimer();
          handler.postDelayed(yourRunnable,60000);// this will call runnable every minute.
       }
    }

//If you want to stop call your function every minute the do following.

    handler.removeCallback(yourRunnable);
```